# How to make UICollectionView auto scroll using NSTimer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch

How to scroll UIcollectionView automatically in Horizontal position using NSTimer

I'm working on my project source below:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.endPoint = CGPointMake(0, self.collectionView.frame.size.width);
    self.scrollingPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    self.scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.015 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

- (void)onTimer {
     self.collectionView.contentOffset = self.scrollingPoint;
    if (CGPointEqualToPoint(self.scrollingPoint, self.endPoint)) {
        [self.scrollingTimer invalidate];
    }
    self.scrollingPoint = CGPointMake(self.scrollingPoint.x+1, 0);
}
```

Tried with the above code, but is not working for me.

Comment: You should not an NSTimer for that. A CADisplayLink is linked to the display, and as such will give you a better way of updating screen-related events. This is explained very well in the scrollView session of WWD 2015 or WWDC 2014.

Comment: Try setting data source first and reload it in your viewdidload or try in viewwillappear.
Then invoke your timer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

// Swift-3

```
var timr=Timer()
var w:CGFloat=0.0

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        configAutoscrollTimer()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        deconfigAutoscrollTimer()
    }

func configAutoscrollTimer()
    {

        timr=Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.03, target: self, selector: #selector(dashboard_ViewController.autoScrollView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }
    func deconfigAutoscrollTimer()
    {
        timr.invalidate()

    }
    func onTimer()
    {
        autoScrollView()
    }

    func autoScrollView()
    {

        let initailPoint = CGPoint(x: w,y :0)

        if __CGPointEqualToPoint(initailPoint, ticker.contentOffset)
        {
            if w<collection_view.contentSize.width
            {
                w += 0.5
            }
            else
            {
                w = -self.view.frame.size.width
            }

            let offsetPoint = CGPoint(x: w,y :0)

            collection_view.contentOffset=offsetPoint

        }
        else
        {
            w=collection_view.contentOffset.x
        }
    }
```

// this works excellently

Comment: i want to scroll images one by one , i tried ur code it auto scrol whole collection set. i want one by one auto scroll.please update me

Comment: could u check this http://stackoverflow.com/q/39158680/2522603. i just copied from urs answer.

Comment: What's ticker.contentOffset?

Comment: `ticker.contentOffset` can be `self.collectionView.contentOffset`

Comment: Yes this is collectionview.

Comment: this is already in question, but i have check and update the code then its working fine.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.2**

With Runloop and Timer block. Adjust the 0.015 & 0.25 values to match your required speed.

```
    var carousalTimer: Timer?
    var newOffsetX: CGFloat = 0.0
    func startTimer() {

        carousalTimer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 0.015, repeats: true) { (timer) in

            let initailPoint = CGPoint(x: self.newOffsetX,y :0)

            if __CGPointEqualToPoint(initailPoint, self.collectionView.contentOffset) {

                if self.newOffsetX < self.collectionView.contentSize.width {
                    self.newOffsetX += 0.25
                }
                if self.newOffsetX > self.collectionView.contentSize.width - self.collectionView.frame.size.width {
                    self.newOffsetX = 0
                }

                self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.newOffsetX,y :0)

            } else {
                self.newOffsetX = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x
            }
        }

        RunLoop.current.add(carousalTimer!, forMode: .common)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var collection_scroll: UICollectionView! // Outlet
 var Scrollinftimer = Timer() // Set Timer 
 let Image_Scroll : [String] = ["ic_girl1","ic_girl2"] // Set Your Images


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return Image_Scroll.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CustomcollectionCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomcollectionCellCollectionViewCell

    cell.img_scrollcoll.image = UIImage(named : Image_Scroll[indexPath.row])

    var rowIndex = indexPath.row
    let Numberofrecords : Int = Image_Scroll.count - 1
    if (rowIndex < Numberofrecords)
    {
        rowIndex = (rowIndex + 0) // 1
    }
    else
    {
        rowIndex = 0
    }

    Scrollinftimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.startTimer(timersset:)), userInfo: rowIndex, repeats: true)


    return cell
}

@objc func startTimer(timersset : Timer)
{
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseOut, animations:
    {
        self.collection_scroll.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(row: timersset.userInfo! as! Int,section:0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: false)
    }, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should increase `contentOffset.x`:

```
self.collectionView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(self.collectionView.contentOffset.x+1, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna move to a particular cell, use

collectionview.delegate. didSelectItemAtIndexPath(collectionview, indexPath: indexPath of the cell you wanna show)

make sure you write this piece of code when the view is ready, preferably in viewDidAppear(), as well as the delegate of collectionview shouldn't be nil.

Note: if you wanna do this after 3 seconds, say, then you need to use

NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(3, target: self, selector: "showTheCellOfInterest", userInfo: userInfo, repeats: true)

and write the piece of code inside the method showTheCellOfInterest()

Answer (score 0):

```
 var carousalTimer: Timer?
    var newOffsetX: CGFloat = 0.0
    func startTimer() {

        carousalTimer = Timer(fire: Date(), interval: 0.015, repeats: true) { (timer) in

            let initailPoint = CGPoint(x: self.newOffsetX,y :0)

            if __CGPointEqualToPoint(initailPoint, self.image_slider_out.contentOffset) {

                if self.newOffsetX < self.image_slider_out.contentSize.width {
                    self.newOffsetX += 2
                }
                if self.newOffsetX > self.image_slider_out.contentSize.width - self.image_slider_out.frame.size.width {
                    self.newOffsetX = 0
                }

                self.image_slider_out.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: self.newOffsetX,y :0)

            } else {
                self.newOffsetX = self.image_slider_out.contentOffset.x
            }
        }

        RunLoop.current.add(carousalTimer!, forMode: .common)
    }
```

Comment: Note: image_slider_out is my collection view name

Comment: Afer that call startTimer() fuction into at viewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/mohankrishnameruva/AutoScrollCollectionView

You can use this pod **AutoScrollCollectionView**, Just subclass you collection view from *AutoScrollCollectionView* in the storyboard and call this method on the collection view with required TimeInterval **collectionView.startAutoScrolling(withTimeInterval: TimeInterval(exactly: 2.0)!)**

Comment: This gist code not works correctly when changing scroll position to centeredHorizontally

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Code**

```
-(void) autoScrollImageSlider {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        
        if(bannerArr.count == 0) {
            return;
        }
        if (counter < bannerArr.count) {
            _pagerView.currentPage = counter;
            NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:counter inSection:0];
            [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: nextIndexPath atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
            counter += 1;
           
        }else {
            counter = 0;
            _pagerView.currentPage = counter;
            NSIndexPath *nextIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:counter inSection:0];
            
            [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: nextIndexPath atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
            counter = 1;
            
        }
    });
    
}
```